# How can I calculate confidence interval for a mean in R not using confint

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am trying to work on a problem where I try generate random exponential and uniform distributions and sample from them.  Then I calculate the confidence interval of the linear model on them using confint(); however, I don't know how to get the correct confidence interval levels that I got from confint() using mean, sd and qt.

Here is what I have so far:

```
x <- rexp(30, rate=1); x
confint(lm(x~1))
summary(lm(x~1))$coefficients
mean(x)
sd(x)
x.std.error <- sd(x)/sqrt(30)
```

I'm also not sure, how to do this using the runif command so if I can get help with that it would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `confint` in this context is just the ordinary [classical 95% confidence interval for a population mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps). The interval is centered around the sample mean (`mean(x)`), and the margin of error is the standard error you found (`x.std.error`) with a multiplier that comes from the t-distribution (`qt(0.975, 29)`). (This gives the 97.5th percentile of the t-distribution with 29 degrees of freedom; in this context, "degrees of freedom" can be regarded as one less than the sample size.)

To recover the confidence interval provided by `confint(lm(x~1))`, you can use:

```
mean(x) - qt(0.975, 29) * x.std.error
mean(x) + qt(0.975, 29) * x.std.error
```

or equivalently, and perhaps more intuitively:

```
mean(x) + qt(0.025, 29) * x.std.error   # qt(0.025, 29) = -qt(0.975, 29)
mean(x) + qt(0.975, 29) * x.std.error
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say that you're not sure how to do this using `runif`, but presumably it's the same basic process as what you did, but replacing the first line with `runif(30, 10, 15)` for 30 variables uniformly distributed on the interval [10, 15] (as an example).

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I think it should be the CI of the sample mean. You never know the population mean unless you defined the population. also note that the sd function is R is meant for estimating sample standard deviation, using n-1 as denominator

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I think it's right as written; you don't need to estimate the sample mean precisely because it *is* known. Rather, the sample mean and sample standard deviation (i.e. the statistics) are used to *infer* things about the parameter (the population mean, in this case). The vector `x` is indeed correctly regarded as a list of sample data, from which we infer something about the unkown population mean.